# Gsuite setup issue

Tags: email, dns, plesk, mx-record

I am having an issue about Gsuite setting up at external web hosting server. I have a Gsuite account and try to connect it to my domain by changing the MX record of DNS record in my plesk panel. However, the mail service still fails after I configure the correct MX record. I am going to attach pic of my web hosting plesk panel DNS setup and mail failure msg.

[This is my web server plesk panel DNS setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T42XR.png)

[This is the mail failure msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p5sS.png)

Answer (score 1):

You must the email address that you have used to as primary email address for Gsuite. It looks like you are using an alias of the primary email address which is not going to work.